# Filter a picture by its color spectrum

Tags: image-processing

I want to split an image in half and remove all colors from one half which aren't present in the other half. I already converted the image from RGB to YCBCR but I'm not sure (from a theoretical perspective) how I could do that.

Can I use an FFT to check, what frequencies are present in one half and remove the differing frequencies from the other half?

I work with Python.

[image: example]

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean with "remove colors"? Maybe even post an example? The FFT on an YC<sub>b</sub>C<sub>r</sub> image channel has nothing to do with the presence of colors, so I'm really confused where this is coming from?

Comment: You're right about the FFT part, sorry. From what I understand the task I need to check, what color components (I guess simply the CbCr values?) are present in one half and if they are missing in the other half set them to 128 as middle value?

Comment: I added an example, which takes the color components from one quadrant and removes the color components from the other quadrants, which aren't present in the first.

Comment: ok, but strictly speaking, color in your colorspace is a single tuple $(Cb, Cr)\in\mathbb R^2$; if we consider the color signal to be continously distributed, then we are almost sure that no color value will appear twice in the image – so, some "neighborhood" criterion must apply. Anyway, this picture is from some paper, so most probably a proper citation would help us help you understand :)

Comment: Ok I misunderstood the task, it's not about the picture but the CbCr graph. If I want to filter by the first quadrant, I need to filter out all CbCr values which aren't >=0.

Comment: ok, but then you just do exactly what you say: you check every pixel for that condition, and if it doesn't fulfill it, you set it to your value.